# Change button appearance after async command completion or cancellation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want two states of a button that starts async command in WPF.

I use this base implementation of ICommand:

```
namespace DesktopClient.Base
{
    public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : ICommand
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;
        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public async void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            if (_cancellationTokenSource is null)
                await ExecuteWithCancellation(parameter);
            else
                CancelExecution();

        }

        private async Task ExecuteWithCancellation(object? parameter)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            await AsyncCommand(parameter, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }

        private void CancelExecution()
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            _cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
            _cancellationTokenSource = null;
        }

        public abstract Task AsyncCommand(object? parameter, CancellationToken token = default);
    }
}
```

Implemented command for testing:

```
namespace DesktopClient.Commands
{
    public class ConnectAsyncCommand : AsyncCommandBase
    {
        public override async Task AsyncCommand(object? parameter, CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            int step = 100;
            int delayTimer = 0;
            while (delayTimer != 5000)
            {
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                await Task.Delay(step);
                delayTimer += step;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First state of button - ready for action. Content property is "Connect". After clicking async operation starts, and button changes state.

[image]

Second state: ready to cancel the action. Content property is "Cancel". After clicking async operation is cancelled and button should change state.

[image]

I use the toggle button with this style to define appearance of these two states.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 5 10 5"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Cancel"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Connect"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So the question is how to set state of button to first state after async task is completed in MVVM way?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. By me all works as expected.

Comment: Once your command was successful you would have a property on your view model and then have another trigger that would change your button appearance to whatever you want it to be. You could go as far as having a property on your VM that could then be bound to your button's Content property.